# parent:: in instantiated classes

Tags: php

i was wondering why there is no `$parent->function();` syntax in php, but instead we can use `parent::function();` which looks like it's used inside a static class. Am i missing some php oop basics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit it seems strange -- and you didn't miss anything in the manual ^^

But :

- **Generally, when the child class re-defines a method that's already defined in the parent class, you want the child's method to totally override the parent's one**

  - except for `__construct`, I admit -- that's probably why it's said explicitly in the manual that you have to call the parent's `__construct` method yourself.
- Generally speaking, when working with non-static methods, you'll just use `$this` to call methods in the same instance of either the child or the parent class ; no need to know where the method actually is.
- Using `parent::` works fine, even if it looks like a static call

And here's an example of code showing `parent::` works fine :

```
class Father {
    public function method() {
        var_dump($this->a);
    }
}

class Son extends Father {
    protected $a;
    public function method() {
        $this->a = 10;
        parent::method();
    }
}

$obj = new Son();
$obj->method();
```

You'll get this output :

```
$ /usr/local/php-5.3/bin/php temp.php
int(10)
```

Which shows that the method in the parent class has access to `$this` and the properties defined in the child class.

Comment: I really don't think it is strange. Because variables can't contain classes, they must contain objects, which are instantiated classes. Therefore, in order for `$parent` to exist, you would have to instantiate the parent object as well as the child object.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `parent` actually references the static parent class - there is no reason to assume there is an instantiated `$parent` only because there exists a `$child`, and even if there were, `$child` would not have access to `$parent`.

Finally, an instance where the usual `class dog extends animal` OOP explanations don't work! :)

Answer (score 1):

Because using `$parent` assumes that you have actually instantiated the parent class.

If your syntax suggest worked, it would mean everytime you instantiated one object, you were instantiating 2 or more objects.

In PHP, every  variable must contain a string, integer(or other numeric format), array, object, or resource. `$this` contains an object, and it just happens to be the object that you are currently inside.

In order to create `$parent`, you would have to put an object inside `$parent`. You parent class is technically not instantiated, so it cannot be assigned to a variable.

BTW `parent::function();` has access to all of `$this`.

Hence, this works

```
class Test
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo $this->testing_var;
    }
}

class OtherTest
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->testing_var = "hi";
        Test::test(); // echos hi
    }
}
```

And this will error if it is used outside a class, and will tell you it should be declared static.

```
Test::test();
```